# Youtube live stream show "PLAYBACK_CONTROLS_VIEW_CONTROLLER_LIVE_BROADCAST_LABEL_TEXT" text on player

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm trying to play youtube live stream in iOS app using https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper library. When player goes full screen, it shows "PLAYBACK_CONTROLS_VIEW_CONTROLLER_LIVE_BROADCAST_LABEL_TEXT" text on player. Please refer screenshot.

[image]

Comment: could you mention a few points regarding what have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to resolved it using Bundle localisation. Create a localisation.String file and add this "PLAYBACK_CONTROLS_VIEW_CONTROLLER_LIVE_BROADCAST_LABEL_TEXT" = "Live Broadcast". Now localise this file.